# Dynamics 365: At sub-grid when I change view, Lookup screen changes and new Main Form shows up

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365, dynamics-crm-365

At opportunity's form, there is a sub-grid [image] to Connection entity.
By default when a user tries to add a new connection, a lookup windows open like [image].
But when I change the view to a custom one, the Main form appears and I cannot change it[image].
Does anyone knows how to populate this Lookup Window when I create a new view for the subgrid?